# Query where Date.parse Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord

I'm using a calendar gem which requires `event.start_time` be recorded as `"2023-11-07"`.

I need to find all events in this month and last month based on the `start_time`, and in which `event.rained_out == false`

```
event.start_time[0,4].to_i == Time.now.year && event.start_time[5,2] == Time.now.month || event.start_time[5,2] == Time.now.month && event.rained_out== false
```

I'm not how to use activerecord query to acheive this.

```
Event.where("start_time[5,2].to_i = ?", Time.now.month)
```

is syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that the `start_time` column in your database is of type string and that you want to find all rows which dates start with a specific string identifying the previous or the current month.

I would start by creating a range for those formatted date string prefixes, like this:

```
date_prefixes = [1.month.ago, 1.month.since].map { |time| time.strftime('%Y-%m') }
#=> ["2023-10", "2023-12"]
prefixes_range = Range.new(*date_prefixes, exclude_end = true)
#=> "2023-10"..."2023-12"
```

Then you can pass that range to a `ActiveRecord` query to find all strings that are included in that range. Which would be all start dates beginning with `2023-10` or `2023-11` but not with `2023-12` because of the `exclude_end = true`.

```
Event.where(start_time: prefix_range)
```

This basically translates into a SQL query like this:

```
start_date >= '2023-10' AND start_date < '2023-12'
```

Putting everything together into a scope:

```
# in app/models/event.rb
scope :started_this_or_previous_month, -> {
  where(
    start_date: Range.new(
      *[1.month.ago, 1.month.since].map { |t| t.strftime('%Y-%m') }, true
    )
  )
}

# use scope like this:
Event.started_this_or_previous_month.where(rained_out: false)
```

Btw. even if the gem you are using requires `start_date` to be a string. You might want to consider adding a column to your table like `start_at` or `start_on` of type datetime or date and keep both columns in sync. That would make database queries much easier.

Comment: beautiful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `start_time` is a textual column in your database.

The reason why you are getting a syntax error is because **you wrote ruby code in a SQL field**.

**REMEMBER**: whatever *String* you put in an Arel `where` method (that is, `where('...')`) will be passed as is to the underlying DBMS.

If you really want to implement that algorithm, you should use a valid SQL syntax inside `where` method:

```rb
Event.where('SUBSTRING(start_time, 6, 2)::integer = ?', Time.now.month)
```

If instead `start_time` is a date/timestamp column, you can write:

```rb
Event.where('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_time) = ?', Time.now.month)
```

The above examples are valid for PostgreSQL DB, if you use something different you should correct the method names.

Comment: I appreciate that, thank you. This is also correct but I have implemented spickermann's solution as there will be additional queries, and I am not fluent yet in PostgreSQL